# Puppeteer takes blurry screenshots of SVG

Tags: d3.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, browsershot

I'm using puppeteer via [browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot) to take a screenshot of an D3 SVG graph. While the graph looks perfectly fine when previewed on the local URL, once I screenshot it with puppeteer it doesn't look as sharp as before.

Manually taken screenshot (sharp):

[image]

Puppeteer screenshot (blurry):

[image]

I'm running the following code with Browsershot. It's a wrapper around puppeteer.

```php
// take a screenshot and save it as a file for now
Browsershot::url('http://dev.project.com/' . $insight->slug . '/chart')
    ->windowSize(1200, 600)
    ->waitUntilNetworkIdle()
    ->setDelay(10000)
    ->save($temp_file_path);
```

I've tried tweak the viewport and screenshot sizes - always the same. Maybe someone has an idea what I can try out/look at?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Browsershot has an [option image quality](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot#formatting-the-image).

```
Browsershot::url('https://example.com')
    ->setScreenshotType('jpeg', 100)
    ->save($pathToImage);
```

Comment: The file extension I'm using is PNG, that should be loss-less, right?